# Handling 2000 vs 1900 in converting character dates to usable dates in R survey data

Tags: r, date, types, survey

I am working on cleaning up some survey data and trying to conver the character dates to usable dates but the functions are automatically assigning some two digit years to 1900 and some 2000 and I am having trouble figuring out how to write the codeo so it assumes any two digit year equal to or less than 23 will be prefaced with 20 (ie 2001, 2002, ... 2023) and all other two digit years will be prefaced with 19 (ie. 1999, 1998, ...1924).

I tried a classic conversion using the following code:

`hd$DOB_new <- as.Date(hd$DOB, format='%m/%d/%y')`

and the output was this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would fix it post-hoc. Do the conversion as you have, and then come back and modify, something like this:

```
problems = hd$DOB_new >= '2024-01-01'
library(lubridate)
year(hd$DOB_new[problems]) = year(hd$DOB_new[problems]) - 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `sub`:

```
date <- '01-01-24'

as.Date(sub("(..)$", "19\\1", date), "%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "1924-01-01"

as.Date(sub("(..)$", "20\\1", date), "%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "2024-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner appends the century and then uses `as.Date`.  The `sub` extracts the last two characters and then we compare that to "23" giving a TRUE/FALSE value which when added to 19 is regarded as 1 or 0 giving the century. No packages are used.

```
x <- c("6/22/94", "6/22/01") # test data

as.Date(paste0(x, 19 + (sub(".*/", "", x) <= "23")), "%m/%d/%y%C")
## [1] "1994-06-22" "2001-06-22"
```